# Displaying Bootstrap Modal in Java

Tags: java, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I've got a login system made in Java for a project, and now I want to display Twitter Bootstrap's modal from the Java code on the JSP page. Is that possible? I've tried invoking the Javascript function, but that doesn't work because Javascript is client side and Java is server side.

I've tried printing a script tag in Java, but that doesn't work either. I can print the modal in Java as well (with ) but I can't dismiss it then.

**The modal I'm trying to display:**

```
<!-- Login Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginmodallabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="loginmodallabel"> Sample Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sample Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Java code**

```
//Checks if the username and password exist for the current selected building
if(LoginDao.validate(name, pass, build, session))
    {           
        response.sendRedirect("/bigdata/dashboard.jsp");  
    }    
else{    
    // I want to show the modal here
    rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");    
    rd.include(request,response);    
}
```

**For reference:** 
Twitter Bootstrap Modal: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Need to look at relevant code here.

Comment: All right, added some.

Comment: How are you calling javascript function on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can print a code in the JSP that would run on the page load. This would go on the page after the java code have decided the modal needs to be shown.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){ 
  $("#loginmodal").modal(); 
} );
</script>
```

Comment: This can't solve the problem. is there any other solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The java code runs on the server, and completes its execution prior to the page being fully loaded. So you can't show the modal "from java". You can have Java generate javascript code that will render the modal once the page is fully loaded (which is what the JQuery event listener I've used does). Am I missing something?